# Constructing from a classmethod

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I am creating a class representing and object in a KV-datastore. Creating the constructor is pretty straightforward...

```
class KVObject:
    def __init__(self, key, value, add=True):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        if add == True:
            kv_create(key, value)
```

Now, let's say I want to retrieve a KV-object... and construct a class instance from it. I figure I'll add this class method onto my DataBaseObject class.

```
     @classmethod
     def get_kv_object(cls, key):
         value = kv_get(key)
         cls.__init__(key, value, add=False)
```

... but when calling **init** from the class method (cls.__init__), Python asks for an argument for self!

Any ideas? Many thanks! I know this is a bit of a simple example, but it definitely applies to some more complex, interesting situations!

**Edit**: Thanks for the responses. I learned something helpful while researching this, which is that object.__new__ calls __init__ on an object when calling MyClass(...), effectively providing an uninitialized instance of the class to MyClass.**init** with the args called from within MyClass. Likewise, it makes sense to call cls(...), as suggested in your answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Think about how you would create a new database object normally, it would be something like the following:

```
instance = DatabaseObject(key, value, add=False)
```

Well within your class method the first parameter (`cls` in this case) is just another name for `DatabaseObject`, so to create an instance you would do the following:

```
instance = cls(key, value, add=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@classmethod
 def get_kv_object(cls, key):
     value = kv_get(key)
     return cls(key, value, add=False)
```

`__init__` does *not* created new instances of the `cls` class! It's a method that's called right after the object has been created.